# How to color these circles in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

How can I color the output of this MWE like the screenshot?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm)      node[right=.7cm, above=.4cm] {$A$};
\draw [thick] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)     node[left=.7cm,] {$B$};
\draw [thick] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)       node[right=.7cm] {$C$};
\draw [thick](0,0) rectangle (6.5,-5.5)     node[left=6cm, above=.3cm] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187729/34618

Comment: See also http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest is to fill the circles first and then draw them.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!50] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm);
\fill[gray!50] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\fill[white] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\draw [thick] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm)      node[right=.7cm, above=.4cm] {$A$};
\draw [thick] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)     node[left=.7cm,] {$B$};
\draw [thick] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)       node[right=.7cm] {$C$};
\draw [thick](0,0) rectangle (6.5,-5.5)     node[left=6cm, above=.3cm] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can colour each region by suitably clipping:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!50] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm);
\fill[gray!50] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\fill[yellow] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
  \fill[blue!50] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
  \clip (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm);
  \fill[red!50] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
  \clip (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
  \fill[olive!50] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
  \clip (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
  \clip (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm);
  \fill[green!50] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\draw [thick] (3.25,-2) circle (1.5cm)      node[right=.7cm, above=.4cm] {$A$};
\draw [thick] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)     node[left=.7cm,] {$B$};
\draw [thick] (4,-3.5) circle (1.5cm)       node[right=.7cm] {$C$};
\draw [thick](0,0) rectangle (6.5,-5.5)     node[left=6cm, above=.3cm] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply but I want to learn the general solution. For example your solution doesn't work if we want to color the region between `A\cap B` (I'm working on Venn diagrams). Could you please help me to color this region?

Comment: @Sisabe Please see the edit.