# Tikz Venn diagram - ellipse style

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to TiKz and I would like to receive your help in how to draw the image below.

Do you know some similar code I can work with, in order to reproduce such image?

I found such topic, with a `similar` code, but using circles. I tried to make this work with ellipse, but unfortunately no success:

[Venn diagram with customized colors in overlapping regions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250919/venn-diagram-with-customized-colors-in-overlapping-regions/250937#250937)

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something hand made, which you can use as starting point ...

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw, circle, thick, blue, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2cm, align=center] at   (0,0)   {Data\\\\};
        \node [draw, circle, thick, red,  fill=red!20, minimum size=2cm, align=center] at    (2,0)   {Domain\\\\};
        \node [draw, circle, thick, brown,fill=brown!20, minimum size=2cm, align=center] at (1,-1.75){\\\\Thinking};

        \node [circle, minimum size=2.1cm, fill=white, opacity=.7, align=center] at (1,-.8){Data\\Science};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, dash dot, rotate=30, brown, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=5cm, align=center] at   (2,0)   {};
        \node [align=center, brown!70!black] at (4.5,1.2){Sociology};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, dash dot, rotate=90, green!50!black, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at   (1,.6)   {};
        \node [align=center, green!50!black] at (1,3.4){Communication};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, loosely dashed, rotate=90, green!70!black, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=5cm, align=center] at   (1,-1.3)   {};
        \node [align=center, green!70!black] at (1,-4){Statistics};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, loosely dash dot, rotate=150, brown!50!black, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=5cm, align=center] at   (0,0)   {};
        \node [align=center, brown!50!black] at (-2.2,1.2){Management};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, densely dashed, rotate=30, blue, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at   (0,-1.2)   {};
        \node [align=center, blue] at (-2.2,-2.6){Informatics};

        \node [draw, ellipse, thick, loosely dashed, rotate=150, blue!50!white, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=4.4cm, align=center] at   (2.0,-1.2)   {};
        \node [align=center, blue!50!white] at (4.2,-2.6){Computing};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]